# how to correctly destroy AsyncTasks?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have problem with AsyncTasks.

My application is simple: ListView and Activity with custom Extras.
In Activity class I have some AsyncTasks  with DefaultHttpClient (Downloading Jsons, Images)

When I wait until AsyncTask load everything and then go back to list and choose another row everything is fine.

But If I start my activity and immediately press "back", then choose another row, then new activity starts, but with task of the previous AsyncTask ( inappropriate images and strings ).
After a while everything back to normal(AsyncTask download proper content), but I want to avoid downloading unnecessary data.

How to not stop, but remove AsyncTask permanently when I press "back" ? Or maybe is other way ?

I will be grateful for the help.

**Edit:**
Of course I use cancel method:
**Activity.class**

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    lastFM.cancel(true);
}
```

**AsyncTask.class**

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        if (isCancelled()) return null;
        inputStream = getInputStreamFromHttp(urls[0]);
        if (isCancelled()) return null;
        jsonObject = getJSONObjectFromInputStream(inputStream);
        bio = getBioFromJSON(jsonObject);
        return bio;
    }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        if (!isCancelled()) {
            Intent i1 = new Intent(ActivityStation.UPDATEFRAGMENT3).putExtra(ActivityStation.ARTISTBIO, s);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i1);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling

```
myAsyncTask.cancel(true);
```

will attempt to cancel the task. After this has been called, inside the `AsyncTask's` `doInBackground()` method, check

```
isCancelled()
```

to decide whether to stop or continue.

Comment: I used this, but it is still the same issue.

Comment: Do you mean isCancelled returns false even after you cancelled?

Comment: **From Reference:** *Calling this method guarantees that onPostExecute(Object) is never invoked.* 
So why is it called ?

Comment: do you have any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

There are techniques to leverage AsyncTasks to avoid this problem. Rather than dwelling on the details of these techniques, I would advise you to look at Loaders (specifically AsyncTaskLoader) which will handle the nuance of managing state for you. Have a look at this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to kill the asynctask

Shoutdown the HtppClient it will automatically stops the http requests

```
httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown()
```